# Formatting [] array like params Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

here my view code:

```
- @categories.each do |c|
%li.menu-drop
= check_box_tag "categories[]", c.id
.tipo-infor
    = c.title
```

when i submit this form, it generate this url:

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/buscar-projetos-com?utf8=%E2%9C%93&categories%5B%5D=3&categories%5B%5D=4&commit=Pesquisar
```

my question is how to better display this url just like:

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/buscar-projetos-com?categories=2,3,4,5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those `%E2's` and such are the ASCII representation of those URLs and it is much safer to use those when sending data over the internet. Furthermore commas (`,`) are not legal in URLs, so they should never be used as neither browsers nor standard libraries will like them.

If you are concerned about "ugly" URL strings, you could submit your form using the `POST` method vs `GET`, which will hide all params from the user.